# Find the integral from the image given below

Tags: definite-integrals

[Equation problem click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Hsx.png)

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x^4}^{x^3}\cos\left(t^3+t\right)\space{dt}=  \;?$$

Does anyone know how to solve this problem??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes if you edit your question to include the mathematics (instead of an image) and show us what you tried and where you are stuck. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Here is the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left\{\int_{\text{g}\left(x\right)}^{\text{y}\left(x\right)}\text{f}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\right\}=\text{f}\left(\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)\cdot\text{y}\space'\left(x\right)-\text{f}\left(\text{g}\left(x\right)\right)\cdot\text{g}\space'\left(x\right)\tag1$$

So, in your problem:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left\{\int_{x^4}^{x^3}\cos\left(t^3+t\right)\space\text{d}t\right\}=$$
$$\cos\left(\left(x^3\right)^3+x^3\right)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^3\right)-\cos\left(\left(x^4\right)^3+x^4\right)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^4\right)=$$
$$3x^2\cos\left(x^9+x^3\right)-4x^3\cos\left(x^{12}+x^4\right)\tag1$$